# Databinding when source changes from null to object array

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have an MMVM project and with one of my View/ViewModels have an issue with databinding.

The view consists of a few combo boxes, and the user is required to select a value from each combox box. After a value is selected, I need to populate the next combo box.

How can I ensure the databinding works correctly in WPF, since only the the first combo box's value is populated on load. The others are all null, and seem to break all databinding to those attached controls. I have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on my ViewModel, but I think things are getting lost due to the initial null values.

Comment: Then initialize them with empty arrays instead of null?

Comment: Much easier for us to help if you show us some example code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ObservableCollections for each ItemsSource.

Create a new instance of each collection before binding them to your ComboBoxes. Leave them empty, but instantiated so that they are not null.

Then, when you are affecting the content of each combobox, directly modify each collection respectively rather than rebinding the ItemsSource (though I assume you are not doing that since you are using MVVM).